# frida hook android system_server report Error: expected a pointer

Tags: android, frida

I am trying to hook android11 system_server On linux. frida version is 14.2.13.

The script as below:

```
Java.perform(function () {
    var clazz = Java.use("com.android.server.policy.PhoneWindowManager")
    var func = "powerPress"
    console.log(func)
    clazz[func].implementation = function (arg1,arg2,arg3) {
        console.log("Enter " + func + " " + arg1,arg2,arg3)
        this[func](arg1,arg2,arg3)
    }
  }
)
```

The command to launch frida:

```
$ frida -U -l script.js -p $(adb shell pidof system_server)
     ____
    / _  |   Frida 14.2.13 - A world-class dynamic instrumentation toolkit
   | (_| |
    > _  |   Commands:
   /_/ |_|       help      -> Displays the help system
   . . . .       object?   -> Display information about 'object'
   . . . .       exit/quit -> Exit
   . . . .
   . . . .   More info at https://www.frida.re/docs/home/
Attaching...                                                            
powerPress
Error: expected a pointer
    at value (frida/runtime/core.js:170)
    at yt (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/android.js:889)
    at activate (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/android.js:970)
    at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/android.js:745)
    at forEach (native)
    at St (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/android.js:746)
    at Et (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/android.js:737)
    at vt (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/android.js:696)
    at replace (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/android.js:1021)
    at set (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:1010)
    at set (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:925)
    at <anonymous> (/script.js:4)
    at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/vm.js:16)
    at _performPendingVmOps (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:238)
    at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:213)
    at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/vm.js:16)
    at _performPendingVmOpsWhenReady (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:232)
    at perform (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:192)
    at <eval> (/script.js:10)
[device]-> Enter powerPress 44442 true 1
Enter powerPress 46290 true 1
Enter powerPress 52580 true 1
Enter powerPress 53910 true 1
```

The hook looks like work but exception happen!

Comment: I have never seen your way to access a method like an array in Frida before. Typically you use `clazz.func.implementation` for non-overloaded methods. And for calling the original method I would also prefer `clazz.func.call(this,arg1,arg2,arg3)`. Not sure this has an impact on the problem.

Comment: @Robert Thanks, try it but still the same!

Answer (score 0):

this is not how you would normaly hook a function have a look on the official docs
https://frida.re/docs/android/
try this instead

```
Java.perform(function () {
    Java.Use("com.android.server.policy.PhoneWindowManager").powerPress.overload().implementation = function(arg1, arg2, arg3){
        console.log("Enter Powerpress :" + arg1,arg2,arg3);
        Java.Use("com.android.server.policy.PhoneWindowManager").powerPress.overload().call(this, arg1,arg2,arg3);
    
  }
)
```

guessing that you are passing args you will need to specify the type of each arg and pass it to the overload function launch the script it will give you a error and copy paste the correct function overload on both the call line and the implementation line

Comment: Thanks,still not work with your suggestion!

Comment: @lucky1928 sorry made a mistake i fixed it, it should work now

Answer (score 0):

If the method no overrides, then no need to add overload.
Use apply to call original function.

```
Java.perform(function () {
    var clazz = Java.use("com.android.server.policy.PhoneWindowManager")
    var func = "powerPress"
    console.log(func)
    clazz[func].implementation = function (arg1,arg2,arg3) {
        console.log("Enter " + func + " " + arg1,arg2,arg3)
        this[func].apply(this,[arg1,arg2,arg3])
        //or this[func].call(this,arg1,arg2,arg3)
    }
  }
)
```